# Error in yaml code could not find expected ':'

Tags: ansible

yaml code

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:
  #Import Remi GPG key - see: http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
  wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi \ -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
  rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
 #Install Remi repo
  rpm -Uvh --quiet \
    http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

Install EPEL repo.

```
yum install epel-release
```

Install Node.js (npm plus all its dependencies).

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install node
```

I am getting following error when compiling: `ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.`

> The error appears to have been in '/home/shahzad/playbook.yml': line
> 7, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
> syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
  wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi \ -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
  rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
  ^ here
```

```
exception type: <class 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError'>
exception: while scanning a simple key
  in "<unicode string>", line 6, column 3
could not find expected ':'
  in "<unicode string>", line 7, column 3
```

Comment: Could you please post your yaml code? This does not seem to be proper yaml code.

Answer (score 0):

I installed everything from the instructions above, but i used the installer `alien` for converting and installing `rpm packages` on Ubuntu 18.04.
But you will **not be able to install with yum**, since some packages are not in its list.

use alien:

```
 # apt install alien # apt install -y

 # cd /tmp

 # wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi \ -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

 # wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

 # alien -kiv remi-release-6.rpm

 # ls -l

 # wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

 # alien epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

 # ls -l

 # alien -k epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm ; alien -i epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

 # cd /home/user

 # apt install curl gcc g++ make # apt install -y

 # curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -

 # apt install nodejs # apt install -y

 # curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

 # echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

 # apt update ; sudo apt install yarn # apt install -y

 # apt install nodejs ; apt upgrade ; passwd -dl root ; reboot # apt install -y
```

But i still have the same error `Invalid YAML: could not find expected ':':`, but on command `networkctl` it became better for me to see , it says `failed` (although before installing node.js, remi-release, epel-release it didn't sign it like that) which interfaces are not configured correctly.

```
 IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
   1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged

   2 ens11            ether              off         unmanaged

   3 enp2t1           ether              routable    configured

   4 br0              ether              off         failed

   5 vlan5            ether              off         configuring
```

These installed packages let you see the interface error in depth, this method works!!!!!!!! Shahzad Adil shaikh thank your!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error while running commands using PowerShell task in yaml.

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@1
  inputs:
    scriptType: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      Command1
      Commands2
```

I fixed this error by indenting the commands/script block.
You need to indent `Command1` one lever under `inlineScript: |`.

Answer (score -1):

- If you wish to use shell commands in your yaml playbook such as `wget`, you'll need to use the [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/shell_module.html) module:

```
- name: Import Remi GPG key
  shell: wget ...
```

- ":" is a special character in yaml, please read the [YAML Syntax page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) in the official ansible documentation, for quoting.
- As for yum commands, you may use ansible's [yum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html) module.

As a best practice, you may use http://www.yamllint.com/ for debugging your YAML syntax, checking for the exact line & column where the parser fails.